# ¿Como importar firebase en proyecto Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, javascript-import

```js
import firebase from "/firebase";
<-- este es el que no funciona -->

import { createElement, getItems } from "../firebase/products.js";
import { navBar } from "../components/navbar.js"
import { createProduct } from "../components/createProducts.js";

let nav = document.querySelector('#navBar')

nav.innerHTML = navBar();

let app = document.querySelector('#app')

app.innerHTML = createProduct();

getItems();

let submit = document.querySelector('.submitBtn')

submit.addEventListener('click', createElement)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <title>LUCCA</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav id="navBar"></nav>
    <section id="app"></section>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content p-3 modalParent">
                <form id="editForm">
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingName">
                        <label for="floatingName">Nombre</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <select class="form-select" id="floatingCategory" aria-label="Floating label category">
                            <option selected>Seleccionar</option>
                            <option value="1">Camisas</option>
                            <option value="2">Trajes de baño</option>
                            <option value="3">Buzos</option>
                        </select>
                        <label for="floatingCategory">Categoria</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
                        <span class="input-group-text">.00</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Leave a comment here" id="floatingTextarea"
                            style="height: 100px"></textarea>
                        <label for="floatingTextarea">Descripción</label>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary saveEdit">Guardar cambios</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/myScript.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="/firebase/products.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Instale firebase mediante npm con el comando *npm install --save firebase* y cuando intento importarlo en mi archivo firebase.js me sale este error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Error al resolver el especificador del módulo "firebase". Los especificadores de módulo relativos deben comenzar con
> “./”, “../” o “/”.

Por lo cual pruebo todas esas opciones agregandolas al import y luego de eso me aparece lo siguiente:

> El módulo de carga de “ejemplo/firebase/” se bloqueó debido a un tipo MIME no permitido (“text/html”).

En index.html tengo linkeado el script de la siguiente manera:

```
src="/firebase/firebase.js" type="module"
```

Ya que sin el `'type module'` me salta el siguiente error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level
> of a module

De la unica manera que consigo hacerlo funcionar es importando cada uno de los elementos a utilizar mediante la cdn, ejemplos:

```
src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.1/firebase-app.js"

src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.1/firebase-firestore.js"

src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.1/firebase-storage.js"
```

Pero claro, la idea de haberlo instalado mediante *npm* es no tener que estar utilizando las cdns, por algun motivo o error que no estoy captando no me reconoce que esta instalado en mi proyecto .. ¿alguien puede ayudarme?

Comment: Puedes compartir todo el código en donde estás tratando de utilizar firebase?

Comment: Ya lo he editado @AndresGardiol